# Can't post JSON to Jersey

Tags: json, maven, tomcat, post, jersey

I can't get a Jersey service to consume JSON.  I keep getting a 415 unsupported media type error.   Here's my service class and method.  The GET request works as does a POST with plain text, but testing with a URI that uses the third method with JSON generates the error.   The documentation inside Jersey said to uncomment the media-moxy dependency to add JSON functionality which I've done but it doesn't affect the behavior.  I'm running this inside Tomcat with the web.xml below

```
package com.example;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/myresource")
public class MyResource {

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getIt() {
    String path = "Got it";
    return "Got it!";
}


@POST
@Path("/testpost/{x}")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String testPost (@PathParam("x") String sessId) {
    return "{a: \"333\"}" ;
}

@POST
@Path("/testjson")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String testjsonpost ()
{
    return "{json-received: \"333\"}" ;
}

}
```

My maven dependencies are:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.23.2</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It worked for me.